# $-log(x) \in L^p((0,1))$ for $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

i proved that $-log(x)\in L^p((0,1))$ for $1<p<\infty$, but how can i prove that it's true for $0<p<1$ too? Any suggestion or hint? Thank you!!

Comment: Well, smaller $p$ reduces growth near $0.$

Comment: Ok, i think that if i prove that $|logx|\leq c*(1/\sqrt x)$ i have done, right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|\log x|\le 1$ on $[1/e,1].$ Hence $|\log x|^p\le 1$ on $[1/e,1]$ for $0<p<\infty.$ So we need worry only about what happens on $(0,1/e],$ where $|\log x|> 1.$ You have shown $|\log x|\in L^2(0,1/e].$ Since $|\log x|^p \le |\log x|^2$ on this interval for $0<p<2,$ we're done.